HTML XPATH, get aunt/uncle html

I was able to get access to the tag that contained CSCI 12
"//span[contains(., '" + CSCI + "') and contains(., '" + 12 + "')]"

but im stuck trying to access the parents sibling (aunt/uncle)
"//span[contains(., '" + CSCI + "') and contains(., '" + 12 + "')]"..//following-sibling::table[1]" 

Also would contains access the element that contains 112 aswell as 12 is in 112?

Can you share the URL of the site if it's public? Also, you should not share the HTML as an image, it should be as a text.

Try "//span[contains(., '" + CSCI + "') and contains(., '" + 12 + "')]"../following-sibling::table"  -- basically just one forward slash before following-sibling. Let us know how you get on.

Following up on @Shawn comment, please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?. If you think the image adds useful information then you can include the image in addition to properly code-formatted textual contents.

Try this:
//div[span[contains(., 'CSCI') and contains(., '12')]]/following-sibling::div[1]/table[1]

In this way you bring the context to the parent div.
On that div you put the predicates with the span with it's properties
And than you use /following-sibling::div[1] to get to the first following div and by /table[1] you get to the first child-table of that following div
